# Why O-H bond and not C-O bond breaks in Acid Catalyzed Hydration of Alkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, bond

Recently, while studying Hydrocarbons I came across this reaction (Acid catalyzed hydration of an alkene) [image]

What I don't get here is that the breaking of O-H bond (in Step 3) and not the C-O bond, even though the C-O bond is weaker than O-H bond.

Comment: If the C-O breaks then you have gone back to the product of step 1. Note that these steps are all reversible, but you only get the product by the O-H bond breaking, and experiments show that you do get the product

Comment: To reiterate: the C-O bond **does** break all the time, and form again, and break again, and form again.

Comment: @Waylander The 3rd step is mentioned to be fast so i think it's almost irreversible ?

Comment: What I don't get is the reason why O-H bond breaks when C-O bond *can* break more readily ig

Comment: Fast does not equal irreversible. The product alcohol can and does protonate under the reaction conditions

Comment: You are equating the RO-H bond strength with the strength of the bond of ROH2+ they are not the same

Comment: Also note that "bond strength" values typically refer to homolytic bond cleavage, whereas all of the steps shown involve heterolytic cleavage, so your premise is incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

As I can see in the 3rd step you’re referring to its a reversible process thus major and minor products are also formed so I think the breakage of the C-O bond would fall under one of the minor product, and the breakage O-H bond will fall under major product.
I also think the oxygen's octet conditions would not be allowing it to do so.

Comment: I think the bond energy of         C-O(358kJ/mol) is less than  O-H(463kJ/mol)

Answer (score -3):

I can see your concern about the Bond Dissociation Energy of the O-H bond being higher than that of the C-O bond.

A key point to consider here would be that the oxygen in question carries a **positive formal charge**, making it more electronegative and exhibiting a stronger [-I effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_effect).

This effect is experienced by both the adjacent carbon and the hydrogens; However, the carbon in question is a tertiary carbon and the three methyl groups stabilise the 'electron deficiency' of the carbon attached to oxygen by compensating with +I effects.

**Hence, the hydrogen attached is electron deficient, and carries a partial positive; making it susceptible to attack by the lone pair on oxygen.
Note that either Hydrogens could be attacked, and we get the desired product.**

Hope this helps :)